# Django RF ModelSerializer get current user's userid

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to move all my create,update method from my views to serializer.py, I read keep your views thin while serializer fat.

```
class APIClerkView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
serializer_class = ClearanceItemSerialize

  def perform_create(self, serializer):
     serializer.save(recorded_by=self.request.user.userid)
```

here I have simple create that save the current user userid to recorded_by, How can I do that in my ModelSerializer

Edit: For my update method I was using instance.resolve etc... how can I make this work if there's two return both ***instance*** and ***super().create(validated_data)***

```
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    instance.resolve = 'True'
    instance.resolve_date = timezone.now()
    validated_data.resolve_by = self.context["request"].user.userid 
    

    TransactionLog.objects.create(cl_itemid=ClearanceItem.objects.get(cl_itemid=instance.cl_itemid),
      trans_desc="Resolve Clearance Item",
      trans_recorded=timezone.now())
    return instance
    return super().create(validated_data)
```

Edit2:

```
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    instance.resolve = 'True'
    instance.resolve_date = timezone.now()
    instance.resolve_by = validated_data.get(self.context["request"].user.userid, instance.resolve_by)
    instance.save()
    return instance
```

Edit: I got it working by using this

```
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    instance.resolve = 'True'
    instance.resolve_date = timezone.now()
    instance.resolve_by = self.context["request"].user.userid

    TransactionLog.objects.create(cl_itemid=ClearanceItem.objects.get(cl_itemid=instance.cl_itemid),
      trans_desc="Resolve Clearance Item",
      trans_recorded=timezone.now())
    instance.save()
    return instance
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply override the **`create(...)`** method of the serializer

```py
class ClearanceItemSerialize(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # other fields and meta
    def create(self, validated_data):
        # attach the user to the validated data
        validated_data["recorded_by"] = self.context["request"].user
        return super().create(validated_data)
```

Comment: I edit the question can you help me with the update method? before I was using instance but now that there the validated_data parameter how can I combine or rather how to make this work

Comment: Nothing fancy here - just inject the logged-in user by adding data into the `validated_data` dict - just like `validated_data["recorded_by"] = self.context["request"].user`

Comment: I edit it again can you look I try to use both and there's no error but it's not updating